# Ember.js template rendering

Tags: ember.js

I'm possibly reading the docs wrong. Can someone please [check out my gist](https://gist.github.com/mjallday/5087204) and tell me why the `invoices/index` template is not rendering?

When I read [the ember.js docs](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/) it states it should render

```
posts
 ↳posts/index
```

(`invoices/index` in my case). The `invoices` template renders however.

**Handlebars:**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
    <h1>Ember Committers</h1>
    <nav>
        {{#linkTo "index"}}Index{{/linkTo}}
        {{#linkTo "about"}}About{{/linkTo}}
        {{#linkTo "invoices"}}Invoices{{/linkTo}}
    </nav>
    {{ outlet }}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="invoices">
    <h1>Invoices</h1>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="invoices/index">
    <ul>
        {{#each invoice in invoices }}
        <li>{{#linkTo "show" invoice.id}}{{ invoice.id }}{{/linkTo }}</li>
        {{/each }}
    </ul>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="invoices/show">
    <p>Invoice - {{ name }}</p>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="phone">
    <p>Contributor - {{ title }}</p>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="about">
    <p>About {{ title }}</p>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    <p>Index</p>
</script>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" defer>
    var App = Ember.Application.create({
        LOG_TRANSITIONS: true
    });
    App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
        templateName: 'application'
    });

    App.Router.map(function () {
        this.route("about");
        this.resource("invoices", { path: "/invoices" }, function () {
            this.resource("show", { path: "/:id" });
        });
    });

    var invoices = [
        {id: 1},
        {id: 2}
    ];

    App.AboutRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
        setupController: function (controller) {
            // Set the IndexController's `title`
            controller.set('title', "My App");
        }
    });

    App.InvoicesIndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
        invoices: invoices
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include an `{{outlet}}` tag in your `invoices` template. Since `index` and `show` are nested resources of `invoices`, their templates get rendered inside the outlet that you specify in the `invoices` template.

Take a look at the [nested resources](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_nested-resources) part of the Ember.js guide.